# Command line to create a Maven artifact and having as input *.java files of a directory

Tags: java, maven

I have a directory which contains *.java files generated by a C++ project build.

I need a command line to create a ***.jar file** which :

1. contains the **generated *.java** files. These java files initially exist **in a directory** that I would specify to the command line;
2. the *.java files must be placed in a **package** that I would specify  to the command line;
3. must be a **Maven artifact**, of **type .jar** and so which has a **version**, a **groupId**, and **artifactId**  that I would specify to the command line;

I need this **command line** to be executed in a post-build for my C++ project build.

Thank you

Comment: you can go through [maven in 5 mins](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

Comment: A maven artifact is just a jar file that is stored in a repository. What is your specific problem? What did you try already? What does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a correct pom.xml you can start maven with the following command:

```
mvn clean install -Dproject.build.sourceDirectory=<your directory>
```

Though maven can be irritating when you don't use the default of "src/main/java"

Regarding 2.:

Passing the java package as a command line parameter is problematic, as the .java-Files must declare the correct package and must be located in a matching directory.

You could use the filtering mechanism of the maven-resources-plugin to replace a wildcard in your source files with the actual package, but you would need an existing pom.xml with the configuration for the plugin.

Comment: No sir, my question is : What should be the command line to create a jar file that can be used as a dependency in a Maven project? My input is *.java files that exist in a directory, only.

Comment: That's what this is, assuming that you have the required POM. There is no single command that does what you want without a POM.

Comment: And is there a command line to create the POM file? Because everything should be automated... I really do have only *.java files.

Comment: Here is a tutorial how you can tell maven to generate a project (including pom.xml): http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html